# Git pull times out

Tags: ssh, git

I just updated my server from Debian 5 to Debian 6 and now when I try to `git pull` (Or any git command it seems) I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host bhslaughter.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I had set up gitosis as well.  Also I'm not sure if its related but when I do `ssh localhost` I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost: Name or service not known`.  Same for if I type out 127.0.0.1.  SSH is working though, as I'm using it to connect to the server.  Any idea whats causing this?

Edit:

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       bhslaughter.com boslaughter.com ruinvalor localhost localhost.localdomain
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
ff02::3         ip6-allhosts
```

Edit2:

resolve.conf:

```
nameserver 173.45.224.5
nameserver 173.45.224.4
```

nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Do you have the IPv4 **and** IPV6 entries for localhost in the /etc/hosts of the server ? ssh uses DNS and DNS uses the hosts file, and IPv6 disabling, works different from lenny to squeeze.

Comment: @poisonbit I think so, I posted the contents of my hosts file above

Comment: "Could not resolve hostname localhost" points to some problem on that file... maybe "127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost" as a first line, then 127.0.1.1 with your other aliases ? loopback network is 127.0.0.0/8 so everything should continue working with this test.

Comment: What's in your /etc/resolv.conf and the files line of your /etc/nsswitch.conf?

Comment: @poisonbit I made the changes, didnt seem to help.  @justarobert: I posted the contents of those two files above

Comment: dns for localhost should be ok now... If doesn't work... I don't know where to continue... does "ping localhost" resolve to 127.0.0.1 ? in such case only custom entries in $HOME/.ssh/config comes to my mind.

Comment: ping does resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1 but the pings never go through.  Theres nothing in $HOME/.ssh/config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.  iptables was restoring rules before the localhost adapter was initiated.  For some reason after the upgrade the rules file became invalid, making the restore fail and causing the localhost adapter to not be loaded.